# set AWS_PROFILE is not working for powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I have multiple profiles in my aws config file. Instead of adding --profile in each command, I want to set the profile to a particular profile before executing the commands. I tried using "set AWS_PROFILE profilename". It's working when I open new powershell prompt but I want in the same prompt. Sometimes it's not working even in new prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `AWS_PROFILE` doesn't do anything at all for me. (Looks like there's an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1083) open for it.)

You can achieve the same result with `Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName [...]` though. If you've already set the environment variable you can just do:

`Set-AWSCredential -ProfileName $env:AWS_PROFILE`